# How to expand the key before which there is a non-key string?

Tags: emacs, yasnippet

For example, this is my snippet in python mode:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: (
# key: (
# --
($0)
```

I can expand `(`to `()`, but I can not expand `a(` to `a()`.

How to expand `a(` to `a()`?

Comment: Your question isn't completely clear.  Could you add more detail such as "When I do... I expect... but instead... happens"?
Also, please specify your emacs version.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't use them, there are minor modes like smartparens mode (https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens) which automatically inserts  or deletes the matching brackets which will probably work a lot better than using snippet.